# Исправить строку в зале славы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Нашёл недавно такую проблему на [странице рейтинга участников](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2019-01-01?sort=reputationchange):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю, стоит убрать скобку возле `prev year`. Такая же проблема есть и на `enSO`. Или это так и задумано? :)

Comment: [Спросил на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348203/260198).

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, спасибо :) я вот кстати не смог найти в процессе публикации вопроса здесь метку `зал-славы` :(

Comment: Всегда можно самому создать)

Comment: хм... такого я не смог предвидеть :)